# Sublime text 3 and overriding settings per project doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I've setup to my user settings on sublime text 3, the following option: `trim_trailing_white_space_on_save: true`

But it seems our collagues have a different opinion regarding of it and if it is useful. So I have to override this setting per project (I wanted to other projects, I just want to be skipped on a specific one). I've tried by creating a file `.sublime-workplace` and/or `.sublime-project` on the root of the project folder and I added the following:

```
{
  "settings":
  {
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": false
  }
}
```

But when I save a file with whitespaces, it still keeps trimming them. What am I doing wrong? Is there specific settings which I can bypass per-project? If yes, is there another way of doing that (maybe a sublime plugin or something).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the description in your question, the problem may be that you created the project file but didn't actually open it. Sublime only treats paths with a project file in them specially if you open the project, e.g. via `Project > Open Project` or from the command line via `subl --project path/to/project.sublime-project`.

Additionally, without a list of paths to include in the project, the project defaults itself to being empty, which is probably not what you want.

From your existing window that you're already working with, select `Project > Save Project As...` to save a project and workspace that captures the current state of everything; folders visible in the side bar as well as any files that may already be open. Once that's done you can use `Project > Edit Project` to edit the project file and add the setting as you did above.

Aside from that, a project file like the following saved into the folder you're using for your project will also do what you want; just remember to use `Project > Open Project...` or `Project > Switch Project...` to open the file you've created so that Sublime will use it.

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've created a project file through sublime, I open it as you suggested and it worked.